# Node.js MongoDB - collection.find().toArray(callback) can not excute

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

I want to read data from MongoDB and write them to MySQL.
There are so much rows in Mongo and I think should use each to insert them into MySQL, but I don't know am I  right.

My code like this:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    console.log(Date() + "mongoDb connect success");

    async.parallel([
        function() {
            conn.query(selectAllOrders, function(error, rows, fields) {
                if (error)
                    console.log(Date() + 'error');

                console.log(Date() + ' row length:', rows.length);
                async.eachSeries(rows, function(order) {
                    findTakerLocus(db, 'position_2015_06_15', {}, function(res) {
                        console.log(res);
                    });

                }, function(error) {
                    console.log(Date() + 'error:' + error);
                });

                console.log(Date() + 'you are not right');
            });
        },
        function() {
            db.close();
            console.log(Date() + 'mongoDb关闭连接');
            conn.end();
            console.log(Date() + 'mysql 连接关闭');
        }
    ], function(err, results) {
        log('1.1 err: ', err);
        log('1.1 results: ', results);
    });

});

var findTakerLocus = function(db, collectionName, key, callback) {
    var collection = db.collection(collectionName);

    collection.find(key).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        console.log(' excute callback');
        callback(docs);
    });
}
```

Comment: Try to check the error in the callback of mongo db connection.

Comment: You are running your two functions in parallel. Your first function is running the query to find the data you want but the second function in your async. parallel() call is immediately closing the database connection. Also the way you are using the async library the parallel call is not going to know when it is done since you are not using the callbacks in the functions https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback